# Load Balancing opentsdb clients using Nginx

Tags: nginx, opentsdb

I have configured Nginx to load balance opentsdb clients installed in centos. The configuration looks like below

```
events {}

http {
    upstream opentsdblb {
      least_conn;
      server 10.42.34.11:4242;
      server 10.42.34.12:4242;
    }

    server {
     listen 80;

     location / {
      proxy_pass http://opentsdblb/;
     }
    }
}
```

When hitting the URL I am getting a bad gateway. Am I missing something here?

curl http://10.42.34.12

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.16.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note: Nginx is installed in 10.42.34.12**

Answer (score 0):

I checked the Nginx error logs and found that there is a permission issue.

```
*1 connect() to 10.42.34.11:4242 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream
```

sudo cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep nginx | grep denied

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1574848605.888:133226): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  
The issue is resolved by setting the
```

After setting the below and restarting nginx the issue is resolved.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```